# Android Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) build error

Tags: android, android-studio, armv7

I am getting the following error when I compile the Android project, what could be the cause of this error?

"Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) "

My Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "facebook.f8demo"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11"
            }
        }
        ndk {
            // Specifies the ABI configurations of your native
            // libraries Gradle should build and package with your APK.
            abiFilters  'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.so'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Source code of the project [Caffe2AICamera](https://github.com/mesutpiskin/AICamera)

[image: Android Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)]

Answer (score 1):

For me, I am using Android-25, but I have to use arm64-v8a because it's 64-bit. I think armeabi-v7a is 32-bit. See this for a breakdown of ABI management on Android: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html